# Django - Ordered ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, database-design

I have 2 models in my Django app: `Operation` and `Job`. `Job` model has a many-to-many relationship with `Operation` model. I use `Job` model to run multiple `Operation`s in one go. But I need those `Operation`s to be executed in a specific order. I can use JSONField to store foreign keys in specific order to do this, but is there a better solution for this? Here are my models:

```
class Operation(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(verbose_name='Operation name',max_length=50)
    merger_operation=models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Merger operation',default=False)
    parser_action=models.ForeignKey(ParserAction,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Parser action')

class Job(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(verbose_name='Job name',max_length=50)
    operations=models.ManyToManyField(Operation,verbose_name='Pre-request operations')
```

Comment: Sometimes I have used  `django-sortedm2m` for this: https://github.com/jazzband/django-sortedm2m

Comment: This solves my problem, thanks !